# Data Seeding for one to many relationship in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to seed data for my new database that has the following schema:

```
public class Meeting {

    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }
    public List<File> Files {get; set; }
}

public class File : IWistiaMiddlewareModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public Media WistiaMedia { get; set; }
    public Meeting Meeting { get; set; }
    public bool Uploaded { get; set; }
}
```

I'm simply trying to add some Meeting and File data to the database so I can have some test data to play around with. Here is my attempt at seeding in the context file:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{

    var testMeeting = new Meeting()
    {
        BeginDate = DateTime.Now,
        EndDate = DateTime.Now,
        Code = "000-2042",
        Description = "A Test meeting to test with",
        IsArchived = false,
        Title = "Test Meeting 1",
        Files = new List<File>()
    };

    var testFile = new File()
    {
        FileName = "The Most Satisfying Video In The World",
        Extension = ".mp4",
        Duration = 259,
        Location = "C:\\Users\\ngoodman\\Downloads",
        Size = 47322483,
        Uploaded = true,
        WistiaMedia = null,
        IsArchived = false,
        Id = 1,
        Meeting = testMeeting
    };

    testMeeting.Files.Add(testFile);

    builder.Entity<Meeting>().HasData(testMeeting);

    builder.Entity<File>().HasData(testFile);
}
```

When I try to add this migration, I get the following error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'File' cannot be added because it has the    navigation 'Meeting' set. To seed relationships you need to add the related entity seed to 'Meeting' and specify the foreign key values {'MeetingCode'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values.

When I run the migration without the seed data, it works as expected. It will also run with the Meeting seed data, but it blows up when I include the File seeding code.

I see that it's complaining that it can't find a value for **MeetingCode**, which is a primary key on the **File** table. While the migration does add a "MeetingCode" field to the generated **File** table, I have no way to set this value since it's not an actual value of the **File** Model. My assumption is that this should occur behind the scenes when I assign a Meeting to a File, but clearly this isn't happening?

Can somebody please shed some light on what's going wrong here? How can I successfully add the seed data for the File table, or for any one-to-many relationship for that matter?

Comment: Not 100% sure what's going wrong there. However, you should be able to leave out the `builder.Entity<File>().HasData(testFile);` and `Meeting = testMeeting`, as the entity should get added & referenced because it's part of the Meeting-entity.

Comment: Is this a migration that only adds the `MeetingCode` field, or is it a first migration?

Comment: @Compufreak That makes sense that those two lines are unnecessary. When I leave them out, I get the same error as before.

Comment: @GertArnold In this example I hadn't added an explicit `MeetingCode` field, but I've tried playing around with that - to no luck. I have tried it both as a first migration and as a migration just to add the data. Neither one seems to work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?